Is this a bad schematic?
I am looking at a circuit diagram for an L298N module from http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=Motor_Driver_Module-L298N#Drecription.

I found that the actual negative part of the diode is connected to VCC and that the actual positive part of the diode is connected to GND (0V.) I was probing around and doing research and found that the side with the band (cathode side) is not showing 0V which is not what I expected.
Why did they connect the positive voltage on the cathode? The only thing that confuses me is that the PCB works as intended.

Diodes have cathodes and anodes, that behave certain way depending on voltage applied. In this case the point is that diodes don't conduct unless illegal voltage is applied, in which case diodes kind of bypass the IC and let the current flow elsewhere.

I thought diodes were protected in that putting a positive voltage of 0.7 or more will stop it but thanks for your answers

Note that pins 1 and 15 of L298 should be wired together (?).

why are they connected to ground

The schematic looks okay electrically, but it uses an L298 so I would call it a bad schematic. 3.7V typical total loss when sourcing/sinking 2A is just terrible. To paraphrase Dorothy Parker, it's not a part to be tossed lightly aside — it should be thrown with great force.

No. The diodes are facing the right way. They are protection diodes, that protect the IC from overvoltage on the pins, which might occur if, for example the pins are driving an inductive load, or for another example, they are driving a capacitative load, and the power supply suddenly gets cut off. These didoes will clamp the voltage at the IC pins to be within -0.7 V and Vcc+0.7 V, as long as the the power supply is able to sink current, and as long as the back-feed current is not so excessive that it overloads the diodes. If the diodes were in the opposite direction, they would short out the power supply and the output pins.

This is the answer.

The diodes are shown correctly as flyback-effect clamp diodes to an inductive load.

The high-side diodes clamp the Low side switch and visa versa to the connected power rail.
The response time Tau= L/Rs for Rs of the combined motor DCR and diode bulk resistance at the current level used when switched off.
However, for high-speed relays the diode will slow down the mechanical delay by damping the current instead of a very small Tau with an arc at some high voltage so a Zener may be added to the forward Vf s but only if relay-off time-delay is critical.
